# How do I get interaction of 2 sets of tuples by a specific element?

Tags: python

There are 2 sets s1 `{(1, 'string111'), (2, 'string222')}` and s2 `{(2, 'string333'), (3, 'string444')}`. Can I get interaction of the 2 sets by id (the first elements in tuples). So the interaction I actually want to get is `{1, 2} & {2, 3}`, but return `{2, 'string222'}`. Or is it better to use other data structures instead of Set of Tuples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or why not:

```
print({i for i in s1 if {i[0]}==set.intersection(set(map(lambda x:x[0],s1)),set(map(lambda x:x[0],s2)))})
```

Output:

```
{(2, 'string222')}
```

Or then why not:

```
print({i for i in s1 if i[0] in map(lambda x:x[0],s2)})
```

Output:

```
{(2, 'string222')}
```

Or `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print({i for i in s1 if i[0] in map(itemgetter(0),s2)})
```

Output:

```
{(2, 'string222')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `set` on all the id in `s2`, for each `tuple` in `s1` lookup `id2`

```
s1 = {(1, 'string111'), (2, 'string222')}
s2 = {(2, 'string333'), (3, 'string444')}

id2 = {x[0] for x in s2}        # all the id in s2
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in id2, s1))  # lookup id2 and filter
print(filtered)                 # => [(2, 'string222')]
```

Non-FP version

```
id2 = {x[0] for x in s2}
ret = set()
for x in s1:
    if x[0] in id2:
        ret.add(x)
print(ret)      # => {(2, 'string222')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more convenient to convert your sets to dictionaries:

```
d1 = dict(s1)  # {1: 'string111', 2: 'string222'}
d2 = dict(s2)  # {2: 'string333', 3: 'string444'}

for i in d1:
    if i in d2:
        print(i, d1[i])
# 2 string222
```

Or more concise (using set comprehension):

```
{(i, d1[i]) for i in d1 if i in d2}  # {(2, 'string222')}

# equivalently {(i, d1[i]) for i in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
```